# jQuery error when creating a widget Uncaught TypeError: self.addNews is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I get: **Uncaught TypeError: self.addNews is not a function**, in the code snippet below... this was working last week, I don't know why now its not working...

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 700px; height: 500px;">
    <div class="mxport-news"><img class="spinner" src="http://noticiasintegrace.solucionesgp.com/news-widget/img/ellipsis.svg"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://noticiasintegrace.solucionesgp.com/news-widget/widget.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Mexicoxport.NewsWidget($('div.mxport-news'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, the error is clear, `self.addNews` is trying to call a function, and the element received is not a function.

What happened? Can't help a lot with this because I don't hava access to the `Mexicoport` jquery plugin. If you have, please check that piece of code.

Comment: you can see the widget.js here https://pastebin.com/hKN4DSm5 line 69

Comment: It's working fine here on the snippet